# Removing first digit from int, but keeping leading zeros

Tags: java, string, int

I need to write code for removing the first digit if an `int` is more than 3  digits. For example if I have `1055` then the output would be `055`. My current code removes the first digit but the problem is it also removes the zeros and outputs `55` instead of `055`. How would I got about to fix this? The variable that I'm referring to is the **checksum**

```
 int checksum = 0;
 int l = message.length();

 for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) { 3
   checksum += message.charAt(i);
 }
 if (checksum >= 1000) {
   checksum = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(checksum).substring(1));
 }
 physicalLayer.sendFrame("(" + message + ":" + checksum + ":.)");
```

Comment: store it as a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously cannot keep leading zeros in `int` data type.
So, keep the result in a `String` copy

```
int checksum=0;
int l= message.length();

for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
checksum+= message.charAt(i);

}

String sChecksum = Integer.toString(checksum);
if(checksum>=1000){
sChecksum= sChecksum.substring(1);   

}


physicalLayer.sendFrame("("+message+":"+sChecksum+":.)");
```

Comment: @super95 my code is not helpful if sum is below 3 digits

Comment: @camikr int is for adding all chars in message. Finally we convert to string and remove first char. Only case it fails if sum<100

Comment: what is all this looping and stuff?

Comment: @scary wombat. Looping is his checksum calculation of message.

Answer (score 0):

You mention if the it is more than 4 digits then

```
int number = 1055;

    String text_no = Integer.toString(number);
    //System.out.println(text_no.substring(1,3));
    if(text_no.length() > 4) {
        System.out.println(text_no.substring(1));
    }
```

But "1055" has only 4 digit then if condition does not work if you need to check only 4 digit and more that for digits then this will work

```
int number = 1055;

        String text_no = Integer.toString(number);
        //System.out.println(text_no.substring(1,3));
        if(text_no.length() >= 4) {
            System.out.println(text_no.substring(1));
        }
```